# How do I make the first letter of a string uppercase?

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Capitalize first letter of string in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1026069/capitalize-first-letter-of-string-in-javascript)

How do I make the first letter of a string uppercase?

Comment: You could achieve this in CSS if that is better for you: `h1::first-letter { text-transform: uppercase; }`

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Here's a function that does it

```
function firstToUpperCase( str ) {
    return str.substr(0, 1).toUpperCase() + str.substr(1);
}

var str = 'hello, I\'m a string';
var uc_str = firstToUpperCase( str );

console.log( uc_str ); //Hello, I'm a string
```